# Is AWSDynamoDB compatible with Fabric's AWS components, Parse, Bolts?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I have an Xcode project and have added Bolts, Parse and Fabric to it. I've added Fabric's Crashlytics, DigitsKit and AWSCognito and they all work fine.

When I add AWSDynamoDB from Amazon's AWS Mobile iOS SDK I get this error in my `project-Bridging-Header.h` "Could not build module 'AWSDynamoDB'"

and in `AWSDynamoDBService.h` this error message: "Type arguments cannot be applied to non-parameterized class 'AWSTask'" Example line:

```
- (AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemOutput *> *)batchGetItem:(AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput *)request;
```

Does anyone know what I'm getting these errors?

Comment: How are you importing the AWS Mobile SDKs in your project? Are you using the same version of `AWSDynamoDB` and `AWSCore`? They need to match.

Comment: The AWS SDK website talks about version format x.x.x (as does the github src) but the only version I can find on the frameworks I download is version 2.

Comment: Where I'm confused is that Fabric downloads AWSCore and Fabric gives me AWSCognito but AWS Mobile Hub SDK doesn't have AWSCongito

Comment: Spoke too soon! AWSCognito is in an "extras" folder of AWS iOS SDK!

Comment: thanks @YosukeMatsuda - I posted an answer but if you wanted to post something "from the horses mouth" I'd be happy to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yosuke Matsuda was correct. Fabric includes a version of AWS that is different to that now available from AWS website.

This are the steps I followed:

1. install Fabric and use it to add Digits and CognitoSync to an Xcode project
2. replace the AWSCognito and AWSCore frameworks with those from AWS iOS SDK (note that AWSCognito is in an "extras" directory)
3. add AWSDynamoDB from AWS iOS SDK

All will compile.